# Using nodemailer and smtp send mail without authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

Below is my code. This works fine with **gmail smtp server**.
But when I use my office one (which does not require authentication) it fails

May be the syntax I am using is wrong.

below is the code working with gmail smtp:

```
    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'xxxx@abcd.com',
        to: 'xxxxyy@abcd.com',
        subject: 'hello world!',
        html: '<img src="cid:logo">',
        attachments: [{
            filename: 'test.png',
            path: 'D:/bbbbb/mmmm/src/test.png',
            cid: 'logo' //same cid value as in the html img src
        }]
    };

    transport.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        console.log(`Message sent: ${info.response}`);
    });
```

As Our company `smtp` does not require authentication,
I have tried below code:

```
 var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("smtps://xxxx@abcd.com:"+encodeURIComponent('') + "@xxxx.xxxrxx.com:25");
```

OR

```
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport("smtps://xxx.xxx.com:25");
```

but all resulted error

```
{ Error: 101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:797:

at Error (native) code: 'ECONNECTION', command: 'CONN' }
```

My guess is syntax is wrong.
Can some one pls correct me

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove [auth](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/blob/master/lib/smtp-transport/index.js#L56) option from the example code when creating an [SMTP Transport](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/#examples) message.

so it should look like the following:

```
  /**
   * Initialize transport object
   */
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "", //Host
    port: , // Port 
    secure: true
  });

    let mailOptions = {
      from: , // sender address
      to: , // list of receivers
      subject: , // Subject line
      text: , // plain text body
      html: // html body
    };

    /**
     * send mail with defined transport object
     */
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,
      (error, info) => {

      });
```

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens: added some sample code, so basically it omits auth object from nodemailer.createTransport

Comment: what host we can add here? will it work with gmail? Do you have any sample host & port