# SMTP server - send emails without auth / password?

Tags: javascript, node.js, smtp

I recently received a request to add functionality to my code.

The final result of my code is a bunch of `.csv` files in the same folder.
The update requires me to send these files by email.
The available and imposed scenario is to do it via SMTP.

Now I have read on it, and also checked the #nodeMailer npm package but they all require the login and password, but my manager said that I do not need one and can send emails without it.

I have the IP address of the SMTP and the email address that is supposed to send the letter from.

Questions:

- how is it possible to send the emails without actually logging in your mail account?
- if nodemailer is not an option, how can i attach files to email as content?
- Are there any npm packages or can you give me solution or links I can read on in order to make this magic happen ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using nodemailer and smtp send mail without authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52161845/using-nodemailer-and-smtp-send-mail-without-authentication)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok After checking a few things and advices I got the following info. I am posting it as an answer if anyone faces same problem in the future.

- You cannot send messages without authenticating unless it is authorized by the **smtp of your company** [check here](/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52161845/using-nodemailer-and-smtp-send-mail-without-authentication/)
- if you are authorized to send emails, but somehow get the error, the 1st probable error if you try to send an email to yourself is the **absence of connection to the VM or the conflict of apiAddresses**. I have fixed it by going through the **VPN** of my company.
- Once this was fixed, the next probable error you can get is the **sendmail error : self signed certificate**. To fix this, I found an answer [here](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/406/)

So, after this checklist completed,The final code of the sendng mail should look as smth like this:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
        host: "", // hostname
        secure: false, // use SSL
        port: , // port for secure SMTP
        tls: {
           rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    }));

 var mailOptions = {
        from: '', // sender address
        to: '', // list of receivers
        cc: '', // Comma separated list or an array
        subject: 'test upgrde nodemailer subject', // Subject line
        html: '<b>Hello world </b>' // html body
    };

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
        if(error){
            console.log("/sendmail error");
            console.log(error);
            res.sendStatus(500);
            return;
        }else{
            console.log("Message sent: " + info.response);
            // if you don't want to use this transport object anymore, uncomment following line
            socketTimeout: 30 * 1000 // 0.5 min: Time of inactivity until the connection is closed
            transporter.close(); // shut down the connection pool, no more messages
            res.sendStatus(200);
        }

        // if you don't want to use this transport object anymore, uncomment following line
        transporter.close(); // shut down the connection pool, no more messages
    });
```